# Taking a partial row in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a data frame. I want to select columns 3 - 6 (variable2 - variable5) of row 3 (id 3) and make that it's own dataframe. example of what I have...

```
rowId  variable1  variable2  variable3  variable4  variable5
  1      x           x2         x3         x4        x5
  2      x           x2         x3         x4        x5
  3      x           x2         x3         x4        x5
```

want I want to take (from row 3)

```
x2         x3         x4        x5
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can subset a dataframe by row and column index like so:

`df2 <- df[3,3:6]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in `dplyr` with :

```
df %>%
  select(variable2:variable5) %>%
  slice(3)
```

Colin

Answer (score 0):

data.frame accepts [] 2-dimensional subsetting with integer, logical or character vectors, i.e.

```
d[ rows, cols ]
```

In your example, you can obtain the desired data.frame by doing:

```
d[3, 3:6 ] # or
d[3, c(3,4,5,6)] #or
d[3, c( FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE )] # etc.
# you can also select on names:
d[3, c( 'variable2',  'variable3',  'variable4',  'variable5' ) ]
```

Note that data frames also accept list subsetting using [[ ]], but in that case the data frame is trated as simply a list of vectors, unlike [ ] which always returns an object of the same class as the source object.